# Is there any way to display text in 1 continuous line in a RichEdit using a loop?

Tags: delphi

I want to display text in a `TRichEdit` using a `for` loop, but the only way I know how to display text in a RichEdit is by saying `richedit.Lines.Add('blah blah blah')`, but when I do this in a loop, each iteration displays its text on the next line instead of the same line as the previous iteration.

Is there a way to display text in a RichEdit using a loop in 1 continuous line, instead of it jumping to the next line each time it goes through the loop?

```
for i := 1 to 7 do
begin
  if (arrScores[i] <> MinValue(arrScores)) OR (arrScores[i] <> MaxValue(arrScores)) then
    begin
      redOut.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(arrScores[i]));
    end;
```

Comment: Yes, you can (obviously!) build a string `S` in a for loop using string concatenation, and then you can do `redOut.Lines.Add(S)`. Alternatively, you can do `for var i := 1 to 10 do redOut.SelText := i.ToString + #32` or similar.

Comment: As an aside, it is rather wasteful to compute the min and max in each iteration.

Comment: [continuous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/continuous), not [continues](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/continues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add text at the cursor position, use `SelText`. And use `SelAttributes` to change text attribute such as color of font.

Here an example that shows floating point values (Random array for the demo) in alternating red and black colors.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    I         : Integer;
    arrScores : array [1..7] of double;
begin
    Randomize;
    for I := 1 to 7 do
        arrScores[I] := Random;

    RichEdit1.Clear;
    for I := 1 to 7 do begin
        if (I and 1) = 0 then
            RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed
        else
            RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
        RichEdit1.SelText := Format('%6.2f ', [arrScores[I]]);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Not a fan of the [`Odd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Odd) function?

Comment: :-)   :-)   :-)   :-)   :-)   :-)

Comment: Or for beginners: `if i mod 2 = 0 then` ([modulo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use the `SelStart` property to move the caret to the desired position, use the `SelLength` property to clear any selection, and then use the `SelText` property to insert the new text at the current caret position. For example:

```pascal
redOut.Clear;
for i := 1 to 7 do
begin
  if (arrScores[i] <> MinValue(arrScores)) or (arrScores[i] <> MaxValue(arrScores)) then
  begin
    redOut.SelStart := redOut.GetTextLen;
    redOut.SelLength := 0;
    redOut.SelText := FloatToStr(arrScores[i]);
  end;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to manipulate certain lines you can do so by directly assigning desired string to specific line.

```
RichEdit1.Lines[0] := 'Some text that is to be shown in fist line';
RichEdit1.Lines[1] := 'Some text that is to be shown in second line';
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The text isn't actually stored in the `TStrings` object.

Comment: I think that @SilverWarrior was pointing out that the Lines property, declared as type TStrings, allows you to manipulate the text as clearly shown in the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Lines

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Then where it is stored then?

Comment: @SilverWarior: In the Win32 control itself. If you create a new VCL application and drop a `TRichEdit` control on the main form and do `procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := RichEdit1.Lines[1];
end` and put a breakpoint on this line and step into it, you will end up in `Vcl.ComCtrls.pas` at `TRichEditStrings.Get` which simply does `SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETLINE, Index, LPARAM(@Text));` and then Windows gives you the text.

Comment: @RobLambden: Very true. But the Delphi object doesn't store the lines itself; it only passes through "get line" and "set line" requests to the Win32 control. (But, as I said, this is nitpicking, and I didn't downvote the A.)

Comment: I stand corrected. I forgot that TRichEdit is a wrapper for Windows RichEdit control. Not to mention the fact that TStrings class doesn't store any strings on itself. Instead it is intended to be expanded with needed code for storing the strings while providing a uniform way fro manipulating with the said strings.